# PriorityQueue to Integer array

Tags: java, arrays, priority-queue

Any better way to convert `PriorityQueue<int[]> pq` to `int[pq.size()][pq.peek().length]`?

`pq.toArray()` gives an `Object` array and I am not so sure how to cast it to an `int` array.

One way I have tried is this :

```
PriorityQueue<int[]> pq = new PriorityQueue<int[]>();
int[] fin = new int[pq.size()];
for(int i=0;i<pq.size();i++) {
    fin[i] = pq.remove();
}
```

But I am looking for better time optimised solution.

Comment: `pq.toArray(new int[][]{})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PriorityQueue` implements [`Collection#toArray(T[] a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-T:A-) that you can use like this:

```java
int[][] fin = pq.toArray(new int[0][0]);
```

*Note that according to your question, you used the untyped version of `toArray()` which takes no argument and returns `Object[]`. This would be equivalent to `toArray(new Object[0])`.*

Comment: I get "Creation of multi-dimensional arrays not supported"

Answer (score 1):

Using Java Stream API you can resolve this problem.

```
int[] fin = pq.stream()
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .toArray();
```

Example:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
        pq.add(1);
        pq.add(2);
        pq.add(3);

        int[] fin = convertToIntArray(pq);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fin));
    }

    private static int[] convertToIntArray(PriorityQueue<Integer> pq) {
        return pq.stream()
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or rather `pq.stream().mapToInt(x->x).toArray()` to avoid the veritable Rube Goldberg machine of toString'ing and parsing an integer just to change it to an int